# Calling a method with an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a playIt method:

```
public void playIt(){
    System.out.println("Playing the Movie"); 
    }
```

It is working but I also need to include the TITLE of each movie. Currently it is only invoking the method. I need to output it like this: 
Die Hard- Playing the Movie

```
for (int i = 0; i < myMovie.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Movie " + movie1 + " Title: " +    myMovie[i].getTitle() + "");
        System.out.println("Movie " + movie1 + " Genre: " + myMovie[i].getGenre() + "");
        System.out.println("Movie " + movie1 + " Rating: " + myMovie[i].getRating() + "");
        movie1 ++;
        myMovie[i].playIt();
        }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(getTitle()+" Playing the Movie");`

Comment: Thanks Pavneet but I need to do so using playIt(); as opposed to hardcoding 'playing the movie'

Comment: The point was that you'd change `playIt` to display that title. You said you'd need to include the title of the movie - that's what Pavneet's suggestion would do. It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: it's clear `playit` is a method of `myMovie[i]` ith object so does `getTitle()` hence the suggested solution

Comment: This worked- thanks @Pavneet_Singh Sorry I was unclear!

Comment: no need to apologize, relax , i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Change the method play like this:

```
public void playIt(String movie){
    System.out.println(movie + "-Playing the Movie"); 
}
```

when invoking the method you must send the title value:

```
myMovie[i].playIt((myMovie[i].getTitle());
```